# What format can I specify to datetime in order to raise an exception if month isn't two digits?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, format

My request: I would like to be able to use `datetime` library in python with the following use case:

```
datetime.strptime("2019215",'Some format')
```

Should return an exception: Incorrect format or something ... Haven't used two digits for the month.

A concrete example for this use case: I specify to a client that I will only accept dates of format YYYYMMDD in a certain input file. Said client mistakenly sends me a bunch of them with YYYYMDD instead, I need to be aware of the error. If I use the format `%Y%m%d` the date will be parsed correctly.

Question : the formats we pass to datetime aren't `regexp`, what is their nature?

Comment: Why don't you use formats like `%Y-%m-%d` that is more understandable?

Comment: `datetime.strptime("2019215",'%Y-%m-%d')` -> `ValueError: time data '2019215' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d'`

Comment: @shotfunner because file names, wouldn't usually contain `-`

Comment: @martineau Indeed, but that's because there are no dashes (`-`) in the date string you are trying to parse `datetime.strptime("2019-2-15","%Y-%m-%d").date()` would be the correct use of the example you gave.

Comment: You could `assert len("2019215") == 8`; then you'll get an [AssertionError](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assert) thrown if it's not the right length?

Comment: @AriCooper-Davis That could be a last resort solution, but I was wondering if there was a pythonic way to do it or a way to leverage `datetime` capabilities